# If a set A has 3 elements and set B has 5 elements then how many one-one function from A to B?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a set formula to find No. Of one-one function?
If so, what theory is involved with it?

Comment: Combinatorics..

Comment: Permutation and combinations?

Comment: Could u pls tell me the reason why it is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements, and $B$ be a set of $m$ elements, $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. To give a $1-1$ function $f : A \to B$ is the same as to say what $Im(f) \subseteq B$ should be, and then give a bijection $A \to Im(f)$. There are $m \choose n$ ways to decide $Im(f)$, and $n!$ ways to give the bijection.

Hence the answer is ${m \choose n} n!$.

Comment: Im(f) is image of f?

Comment: Yes! It is those elements in $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = b$ for some $a \in A$

Answer (score 2):

Let,A={a,b,c} 
To define a one-one function,
For a we have 5 choices and for b we have 4 choices (reason - the function is one - one)
And for c we have 3 choices (same reason)
Thus ,
Total no of one one function =5*4*3=60

Answer (score 1):

You can use permutation here. Then you don't need to care cases that are not one to one.

P(5,3) = $\frac{5!}{2!} = 5 \times 4 \times 3 = 60$

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated:

There are 5 ways from first element of A to all elements of B, then there are 4 ways for next element of A to B, then there are 3 ways for final element of A to B.

Hence total number of one-to-one functions = 5 × 4 x 3 = 60

Comment: But the answer is 60

Comment: How was that obtained?

Comment: @Parul 60 is correct. Did you read it up somewhere or you have an argument?

Comment: Why is 60 correct?

Comment: I read it somewhere.but  I didnt understand it.

Comment: Answer updated please review.